# Why doesn't the following program print the same string twice?

Tags: c

I can't figure out why can't print same string twice.
Here is example code

```
int main(void)
{
    char *source = "duplicate message";
    char *p1,*p2,destination[50];


    p1 = source;
    puts(p1);
    p2=destination;  
    while(*p2++ =*p1++)
          ;
    puts(p2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you aren't allocating the memory for your other pointers.

Comment: Because when the `while` loop is done, `p2` no longer points to the beginning of `destination`. It points to the end of the string. You get nothing the second time. Try `puts(destination)` instead of `puts(p2)`, or try `p2=destination; puts(p2)` (re-assign `p2` to the beginning of `destination`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One other caution. Rather than packing `post-increment` and `assignment` into the `while test clause` followed by an `empty line`, you can make your code much more readable by actually using the line below the `while` for `post-increment` and `assignment`. You must also take care to `null-terminate` all strings. When you are learning pointers, it is often useful to just take out pencil and paper, draw your string representation, and follow the loop logic by hand to confirm the loop is accomplishing all you need:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *source = "duplicate message";
    char *p1,*p2,destination[50];

    p1 = source;
    puts(p1);

    p2=destination;  

    while (*p1)         /* to walk down string, *p evaluates true until '\0' */
        *p2++ = *p1++;  /* dereference pointer, assign, post-increment       */

    p2++;               /* increment pointer to next memory location         */
    *p2 = 0;            /* null-terminate the string                         */

    p2 = destination;   /* reset pointer to beginning of destination         */

    puts (p2);

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$./bin/dest
duplicate message
duplicate message
```

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the cycle your `p2` points to the end of the `destination` string. `destination` at that moment does indeed contain a copy of `source`. But your `p2` does not point to the beginning of `destination`. It points to the end of the copied string stored in `destination`. I.e. `p2` points to an empty string. That's what your second `puts` prints - an empty string.

If you want to print the `destination` string, that exactly what you should write in your code - `puts(destination)`. Why did you decide to express it as `puts(p2)`?

If you want to experiment with it, you can make your `p2` to point to different positions in `destination` after the cycle. If you make it point to the beginning of `destination`, `puts (p2)` will print the whole `destination` string. If you make it point to the middle of the `destination` string, then `puts (p2)` will print something like `"ate message"` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This code might be helpful for you:

```
char *my_strcpy(char dest[], const char source[])
{
  int i = 0;
  while (source[i] != '\0')
  {
    dest[i] = source[i];
    i++;
  }
  dest[i] = '\0';
  return(dest);
}
```

Notice the `const` for the source, which signifies that the function must not change the source string in anyway.